# Excel VBA - Validation for Date and specific string inputs

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

I need to add a Validation to a specific range on an Excel sheet. The Validation should allow any date and simple string inputs like "done" or "tbc".

I know how to add a validation for dates only via VBA but I can't find a way to use two validation types in one cell.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: If you select 'Custom' in the 'Allow' box in the Data Validation window, you can simply enter a formula which must be `TRUE` for the validation to succeed. It's easy using `AND` & `OR` to validate a date range and also allow defined text (like "TBC"). Have you tried something like this?

Comment: Are you looking to do this with a custom formula (VBA Macro), programmatically, or with standard formulas

Comment: Just a quick wonder about the answers giving `IsDate` as part of a cell validation - `IsDate` is a VBA keyword, not an Excel formula.  How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can thing of is to go to custom validation and to use something like this formula:

```
=OR(ISDATE(RANGE),(LEN(RANGE)<5))
```

You can edit it and record it with the macro recorder... Or give code, as proposed.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers so far. I'd prefer a VBA solution.
So I tried to implement the suggestions given by Vityata in VBA and came up with the following. However, I get runtime error 1004. Any help?

```
Sub customValidation()

    Dim rngCell As Range
    

    With Tabelle1
    
        maxCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each rngCell In .Range("L11:O" & maxCell)

            With rngCell.Validation
                    
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=OR(Isdate(rngCell),rngCell=""done"")"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .InputMessage = "Enter date or ""done"""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = "Enter date or ""done"""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        
        Next rngCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The runtime error 1004 is caused by the "Isdate" function. This don't exist in Excel. Only within VBA. See  
Darren Bartrup-Cook comment above. The section of code where this error occurs can be identified by executing the macro step-by-step by pressing F8. One more note: the maxCell variable is probably not declared as Long (outside the macro).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which allows dates or 'TBC'.  In this case covering a column range (part of a dynamic solution)

```
Set rng = wksOpenReview.Range(wksOpenReview.Cells
   (display_row, ro.lco_sd), wksOpenReview.Cells(lngLastRow, ro.lco_sd))
With rng.Validation
  .Add xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=OR(
  NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(" & rng.Cells(1, 1)
  .Address(False, True, xlA1) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""))))," &
  rng.Cells(1, 1).Address(False, True, xlA1) & "=""TBC"")"
```